# problems using php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

i keep getting errors in my code saying that i have a bad '}' or '{' no matter what i change nothinig is working, it's super easy i know... basically it checks to see if one variable is set, and if not are set it dies, if one is set script continues. Any one have any ideas, im sure im going to hit myself for how simple this is.

php:

```
$i=0;
if(isset($inet))
{
    $i++;       
}
elseif(isset($tv))
{
    $i++;       
}
else(isset($voice))
{
    $i++;       
}

if(!$i>=1)
{
    die("you must choose a service")
}
```

Comment: you are missing a `;` after `die(...)`

Comment: You need a semicolon after your `die` statement.

Comment: Maybe if you properly formatted the code, it would be easier to detect the error.

Comment: Note that `if(!$i>=1){` should instead be `if($i<1){`

Comment: I smiled at it too, but it it isn't wrong at all and it doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have put it as a comment instead of answer. But the expression is incorrect. If $i where to be 0, then !$i would result in 1>=1, and not show the message. When it would be 1 or higher, it would show the message, even though the end user has selected a service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i=0;
if(isset($inet)){
$i++;       }
elseif(isset($tv)){
$i++;       }
else(isset($voice)){ // <- This should be elseif or the expression removed
$i++;       }
if(!$i>=1){
die("you must choose a service")} // <- Here should be a semicolon
```

Comment: Well, that did it, never used elseif before. should have payed more attention :P

Comment: Note that the (!$i>=1) expression is still incorrect. If $i where to be 0, then !$i would result in 1>=1, and not show the message. When it would be 1 or higher, it would show the message, even though the end user has selected a service

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
if(isset($inet)){
   $i++;       
}
if(isset($tv)){
   $i++;       
}
if(isset($voice)){
   $i++;       
}

if( $i < 1 ){
   die("you must choose a service");
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten a `;` in the last line and an `elseif`:

```
if(isset($inet)){
$i++;       }
elseif(isset($tv)){
$i++;       }
elseif(isset($voice)){
$i++;       }
if(!$i>=1){
die("you must choose a service");}
```

I hope it works now...

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your code, it helps to see what's wrong with it.

```
$i=0;
if(isset($inet)) {
    $i++;
} elseif(isset($tv)) {
    $i++;
} elseif(isset($voice)) {
    $i++;
}

if($i<1) {
    die("you must choose a service");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following , i think you missed  on elseif

```
if(isset($inet))
{
   $i++;       
}
elseif(isset($tv))
{
   $i++;       
}
else if(isset($voice))
{
   $i++;       
}
if(!$i>=1)
{
  die("you must choose a service");
}
```